# Multiupload widget - create more items inside single node

Tags: 7, media

I am looking for a solution - I want to upload multiple images (media module) into one node, so each image would be separate item. Is there any module out there? I found multiupload module that creates multiple nodes but that is not what I need. Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out the `Plup Upload` module https://www.drupal.org/project/plup which gives a Plup upload widget for images where you can upload multiple images at once to a content.

You can follow the tutorial here:
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/multiple-image-uploads/

```
NB: To fix the missing thumbnail bug add $conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE; to your settings.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using custom module development :

1. Implement [hook_field_schema()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7) in your module's .install file to define what columns are going to be held in your field table (probably file ID (fid), alternative text for the image, title text for the image and the contents of the text area in your case).
2. Implement [hook_field_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7) to define your field type.
3. Implement [hook_field_is_empty()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_is_empty/7) to provide a way for Drupal to know that a particular instance of a field is empty and can be removed when the entity is saved.
4. Implement [hook_field_formatter_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) to tell Drupal the different ways the content of your field can be displayed.
5. Implement [hook_field_formatter_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7) to define exactly how those field formatters defined in step 4 will be outputted.
6. Implement [hook_field_widget_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7) to define the different input widgets for your field.
7. Implement [hook_field_widget_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7) to define the elements that will make up the widget for your field.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the list. Unfortunately I do not have much programming skills:)